# Spring /boot, profiles, java config and bean creation order (Unexpected behaviour??)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-java-config, spring-profiles

I am working on a spring boot app. We have properties files for each environment (dev, int, qa, prd etc). As for the beans, some needs to be created differently for production. So we have this configuration:

```
@Configuration
class MyBeans {
    @Bean(name="someBean")
    @Profile("prd")
    MyBean someBeanProd() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean(name="someBean")
    MyBean someBeanDev() {
        ...
    }
}
```

MyBean is autowired as follow:

```
@Component
public class SomeService 
{
    @Autowired
    private MyBean someBean;
}
```

When starting the application with:

> -Dspring.profiles.active=prd

'someBeanProd' method is getting called (as expected), and the relevant properties file is being loaded (application-prd.properties). For any other profile 'someBeanDev' is being called (as expectyed) and the relevant properties file is loaded.

However, if I change the order of the methods in the config as below, 'someBeanDev' method is being called ALWAYS (even when active profile is prd), but the correct properties file is being used.

```
@Configuration
class MyBeans {
    @Bean(name="someBean")
    MyBean someBeanDev() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean(name="someBean")
    @Profile("prd")
    MyBean someBeanProd() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this the correct/expected behaviour? I expected spring to create the correct bean regardless of the order of the methods in the config file.

Is there a way to define a bean for one profile, and any other profile should fallback to the 'default' profile?

Creating the prd bean in a different Java config class is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use either `@Primary` (without specifying the beans' name) :

```
@Bean
public MyBean someBeanDev() {
    return new MyBean("dev");
}

@Primary
@Profile("prd")
@Bean
public MyBean someBeanProd() {
    return new MyBean("prod");
}
```

In this case, both @Bean methods are called if profile is "prd" but any `@Autowired MyBean` will have only the MyBean returned by someBeanProd().
This case can be useful if you also want to have `@Autowire Collection<MyBean>`.

Or use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` with the bean name (or bean class with the `value` attribute) :

```
@Configuration
public class ConfProd {

    @Profile("prd")
    @Bean(name = "someBean")
    public MyBean someBeanProd() {
        return new MyBean("prod");
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfDev {

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "someBean")
    @Bean(name = "someBean")
    public MyBean someBeanDev() {
        return new MyBean("dev");
    }
}
```

In this case, only one @Bean method is called dependending of the specified profile.

Comment: I tried the approach with @AutoConfigureAfter, and it is still not working.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter too early...Thanks for your response.

I tried the approach with @AutoConfigureAfter, and it is still not working. Interestingly, if the prd config class is alphabetically after the dev config class then spring uses the correct bean (with or without the AutoConfigureAfter annotation). For example:
DevConfig, ProdConfig = working fine
DevConfig, Config = not working
I didn't try the first approach, as I don't want to create beans if they are not needed.

Comment: i have the same behaviour as yours, which is not straightforward IMO. Anyway, i edited my answer (second approach) and this one should work.

Comment: Yes, with the !prd it is working, but it does not fit our requirments. Ideally we need a 'fallback' bean that is created only if it was not created for other active profiles (we have multiple active profiles). 

I don't see why the order of methods within a config class should affect what bean is created.

Comment: i updated my answer again (2nd approach) and this time it should do the trick and matching your needs. I also tried using 2 separated configuration classes (with differents classes names) and it has the same behaviour.

Comment: From the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` docs: "The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this
 condition on auto-configuration classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs after."

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this behaviour too, a workaround would be to keep the different profile beans in different @Profile annotated classes ( it was a bit of an hassle but I remember it worked ok)

E.g.

let's say you have two implementation for bean1 and bean2 in your production profile and two different implementation for your staging profile

you want to create
two configuration classes

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"production"})
public class ConfigProduction {
  @Bean Bean1 bean1(){ return prod impl;}]
  @Bean Bean2 bean2(){ return prod impl;}
}

@Configuration
@Profile({"staging"})
public class ConfigStaging {
  @Bean Bean1 bean1(){ return staging impl;}]
  @Bean Bean2 bean2(){ return staging impl;}
}
```

in your default application.properties
set production (or whatever you prefer) as the active profile

spring.profiles.active=production, to have a 'fallback' like behaviour

Give it a try